# How to express "to pressing random different keys or buttons on a mobile phone"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, idioms

Your 2-year-old child is holding your mobile phone and he is pressing randomly different keys or buttons on your phone.

> [chaotically](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chaotically) adverb  /keɪˈɒtɪkli/  /keɪˈɑːtɪkli/ ​in a completely
>   confused way that lacks any order
>
> The office was chaotically busy today.
>
> The Revolution began as chaotically as it was to continue.

Is it natural to say "**Don't press chaotically on my mobile phone, please**"?

Comment: Not many people would use _chaotically_ when speaking to a two-year-old! If you have to spell it out rather than just say 'Don't do that!', I should think 'Stop pressing buttons like that' or 'Stop playing with my phone' would be more natural.

Comment: No, it is not natural to say that, or anything like that, with any form of 'chaotic!' @KateBunting is certainly correct, especially given who you are addressing.